# Postfix not sending authentication when relaying to local smtp server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp

I have been trying to get my postfix server to relay all of my message to a local SMTP server. As far as I can tell I have everything set up right, but I get a `550 Authentication error`. My local SMTP server works fine when i send a message with something like send mail, just not when I relay a message using postfix. ( I changed my credentials/relay host name)

Here is my `main.cf` file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
myhostname = evconnect.info
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
local_recipient_maps =
relay_domains=*
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/saslpasswd
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
relayhost = [localhost]:587

inet_protocols = all
```

Here is my `/etc/postfix/saslpasswd` file prehash.

```
[localhost]:587      user:password
localhost            user:password
```

Here is the mail log when trying to send a message to my relayhost

```
Jan 14 16:20:51 ip-10-251-110-190 postfix/smtp[5056]: 9A01B24436: to= 
<driver8lpqh2mrx@host.info>, relay=host.info[xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:587, delay=0.69, 
delays=0.2/0.01/0.48/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host host.info[xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] said: 550  
Authentication required (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

Log from raalyhost (Haraka smtp server):

```
[NOTICE] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] connect ip=54.184.245.135 port=44974 
local_ip=:: local_port=587
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running lookup_rdns hooks
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running connect hooks
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running connect hook in dnsbl plugin
[DEBUG] [-] [dnsbl] looking up: 135.245.184.54.zen.spamhaus.org.
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] hook=connect plugin=dnsbl function=connect_first params="" retval=CONT msg=""
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running connect hook in max_unrecognized_commands plugin
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] hook=connect plugin=max_unrecognized_commands function=hook_connect params="" retval=CONT msg=""
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 220 ip-10-251-110-190 ESMTP Haraka 2.5.0 ready
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: EHLO evconnect.info state=1
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running ehlo hooks
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running capabilities hooks
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 250-ip-10-251-110-190 Hello ec2-54-184-245-135.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [54.184.245.135], Haraka is at your service.
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 250-PIPELINING
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 250-8BITMIME
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 250 SIZE 500000
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=5035 state=1
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 550 Authentication required
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: RCPT TO:<DoNotReply@evconnect.com> state=1
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 503 Use MAIL before RCPT
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: DATA state=1
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 503 MAIL required first
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: RSET state=1
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running rset hooks
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 250 OK
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] C: QUIT state=1
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running quit hooks
[PROTOCOL] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] S: 221 ip-10-251-110-190 closing connection.          Have a jolly good day.
[DEBUG] [A0BFEE28-79CE-4719-B23A-05B9990AA397] [core] running disconnect hooks
```

Log when sending emails using swaks(it works)

```
=== Trying localhost:587...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 ip-10-251-110-190 ESMTP Haraka 2.5.0 ready
 -> EHLO host.com
<-  250-ip-10-251-110-190 Hello Unknown [127.0.0.1], Haraka is at your service.
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250-SIZE 500000
<-  250 AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5
-> AUTH CRAM-MD5
<-  334 PGVhMTUwLjE0YWU5NjQ4YjE4QGlwLTEwLTI1MS0xMTAtMTkwPg==
-> ZXZjYWRtaW4gNDU3NDMxOTE0MDk3ODA0ZDk2YzUzZmI0NTg1MmEzNjc=
<-  235 Authentication successful
-> MAIL FROM:<12345@host.info>
<-  250 sender <12345@host> OK
 -> RCPT TO:<host@me.com>
<-  250 recipient <host@me.com> OK
 -> DATA
<-  354 go ahead, make my day
 -> Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 17:01:28 +0000
 -> To: host@me.com
 -> From: 12345@host.info
 -> Subject: test Wed, 14 Jan 2015 17:01:28 +0000
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20111230.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ->
 -> This is a test mailing
 ->
 -> .
```

Comment: Can you get any logs from the relayhost?

Comment: I added the log form my realyhost, a Haraka smtp server that runs on the same server. It almost seems as if no authentication is being sent over at all.

Comment: It certainly does seem to be that way. It also seems like Haraka isn't advertising that it supports AUTH, shouldn't there be a `S: 250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 PLAIN CRAM-MD5` from Haraka?

Comment: The weird thing is that when I try to send am email with Swaks without authentication I get the same error, but when I added the authentication it works. Although I do get an error saying the host is not advertising authentication. Would this prevent postfix from adding it?

Comment: Yes it would, postfix is very fussy about RFCs, and I'm pretty sure it will not send unsolicited anything, be it authorization, or any other information of that sort.

Comment: Swaks actually works fine, I posted the log from sending a message. It looks like the server is averting authentication correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20244/discussion-between-marty-griffin-and-nickw).

Comment: After chatting with Nick, the problems as the Haraka only advertised authentication to requests coming form localhost. I change my transport file/relayhost in main/cf to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with Nick, the problems was the Haraka only advertised authentication to requests coming form localhost. I changed my transport file/relayhost in main.cf to from referring my domain to localhost. Everything is working now.

Comment: Cool, glad it's all working!